# List of different types based on the same interface C# problem

Tags: c#, list, interface, types

I would like to create a interface that I can use with different types. Like a table where columns may be of different types eg Integer, String, Date.

The following articles have been of great help.

[ListBox, list of different objects implementing the same interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099779/listbox-list-of-different-objects-implementing-the-same-interface)

[List of two different Types in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317279/list-of-two-different-types-in-c)

The problem I have is that the i still need a common interface that can handle different types of data. How can I get around this?

Could I just have the main Interface store as a string and have all types converted to and from?

```
interface IMytype
{
    string Item { get; set; }
}

class Myint : IMember
{
    public int Item { 
                 get; // code here  IMytype.Item (get) then convert to int
                 set; //  code here to convert to string then IMytype.Item (set) 
                }
}
```

Example

```
IMytype testint = new MyInt();

testint.Item = 10;

List<IMytype> testlist = new List<IMytype>();

testlist.add(testint);
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Perhaps your return type should just be object

Comment: Re: the idea of converting to/from strings. What is the common code going to do with the strings?

Comment: @Daniel I was just thinking of a common way to store all data. The main idea is to later rewrite code to bind to a datagridview , however, I am thinking of using datagridview in virtual mode because it getting over complicated.

Comment: @HadleyHope did that via a list of objects it was far simpler thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface is a contract that states what behaviour that class will provide. It <strike>does</strike> should not specify what data the class will hold.

You wish to build up a list of objects that conform to a particular contract - you want them all to behave in a particular way. You are getting confused by the fact that these classes will all have a different internal representation - some represent ints, others may represent floats etc..

You need to step back, and decide what shared behaviour you want these classes to implement. This will form the basis of your interface.

So you want to be able to get a String representation of the data. This is one method for your interface.

You want the class to be able to receive a string and convert that to its internal type? Theres another method.

Do these types need to Wangle a Flux Capacitor?

There's your interface.

```
interface IMytype
{
    string GetStringValue ();
    void ReadString ( string value);
    bool WangleFluxCapacitor();
}
```

Think about the shared behaviour first.

Comment: Many thanks I think instead of string I could use T generic arguments

Comment: Basically i would like a list of lists however the later would be a mixture list of strings, integers or dates etc.

Comment: Yes, but you're not creating the list just because you want a list - you are creating that list because you want to solve a problem. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Don't think about the data types, think about what you want to do with them!

Comment: I actually solved the problem thinking about objects and just created a list of objects then conditional methods based type using getype works well

Comment: +1 for `bool WangleFluxCapacitor`. I need to slip that in our corporate code somewhere, just for lols. :)